# Ruby Conditional Route Redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am trying to do route redirection based on some condition

Current route: `192.120.56.45/fetch/foo_id`

I have a method which accepts foo_id and tell us whether its new foo_id or old foo_id, if its new then return new_foo_id and want it redirected to other domain  `192.108.26.85/new/get/new_foo_id`

If old foo_id then no redirection i.e `192.120.56.45/fetch/foo_id`

Current code in routes.rb:

`get '/fetch/:_id' => redirect { |path_params| "#{fooDetector.detectfoo(path_params[:_id])}" }`

Current code in method:

```
def detectfoo(request_id)
      new_id = get_new_request_id(request_id)
      if new_id.present?
        return "192.108.26.85/new/get/#{new_id}"
      else
        return "192.120.56.45/fetch/#{request_id}"
      end
    end
```

Above code is ending in too many redirection in case its old foo_id and entering into infinite loop.

Comment: Why do you want to complicate things? , In the rails routes docs, i didn't check any example of passing the method in routes. Moreover, you are passing the direct ip address in the path??

Comment: Can you please also add the code for `get_new_request_id` method?

Comment: ip address is just for demo purpose, actually am not passing it.

as i have to redirect the route dynamically, hence passed the method in routes.

Comment: `get_new_request_id` just calls db and check for new id by old id and return null in case not found

Comment: I really don't understand your scenario over here, you can go through the rails routes documentation https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Comment: let me try to rephrase my ask here: 
I have a website1 with foo_id as request params and want to redirect to website2 which accepts new_foo_id as request params * 
mapping of foo_id with new_foo_id is available in db(NOT all foo_id will have new_foo_id mapping) * I want to dynamically redirect to new website with new_foo_id, if mapping is present else redirection should not happen

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working ("too many redirects"), because an "old" foo is redirecting back to itself over and over in a loop. What you want to say is "only redirect new foos".

In order to perform this conditional routing/redirect **in the router**, you need to [use a constraint](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints). Something like this:

```
get '/fetch/:id', to: 'new_foo#index', constraints: NewFooDetector.new
get '/fetch/:id', to: 'old_foo#index', constraints: OldFooDetector.new
```

Another alternative would have been to put this redirect at the top of the `OldFooController#index` action (perhaps as a `before_action`).